# Close current modal and open new modal using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have **two modals**, one is **View** and other is **Edit**.

**Issue** is that when I open a view modal and click on edit button then edit modal is open but view modal is still open its will be disappear when edit modal is open.

I am doing like this

```js
$("#editModal").click(function() {
  var id = $("#editModal").val();

  $('#' + id).modal('hide');
  $('#' + id).modal('show');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewTasks_50" class="btn btn-round btn-info btn-icon btn-sm">View</a>

<div id="viewTasks_50" class="modal fade show" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

        <h6 class="pull-left">Code : <label class="modal_label">T-10-Yes</label></h6>
        <h6 class="pull-right">Task Date : <label class="modal_label">17 May, 2018</label></h6>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Progress</th>
              <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Review system generated T&amp;Cs for deploying to website</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>Pending</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editTasks_50" value="50" id="editModal">Edit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div id="editTasks_50" class="modal fade show" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Update">
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need that when I click on edit button then edit Modal is open and view modal is closed.

Comment: can you made jsfiddle for your current code?

Comment: i made it but its make design issue for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is an working example** of how you can do it.

```js
$("#editModal").click(function() {
  var button = $(this);
  
  var id = button.val();

  button.closest(".modal").modal('hide');
  $('#' + id).modal('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewTasks_50" class="btn btn-round btn-info btn-icon btn-sm">View</a>

<div id="viewTasks_50" class="modal fade show" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

        <h6 class="pull-left">Code : <label class="modal_label">T-10-Yes</label></h6>
        <h6 class="pull-right">Task Date : <label class="modal_label">17 May, 2018</label></h6>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Progress</th>
              <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Review system generated T&amp;Cs for deploying to website</td>
              <td>0%</td>
              <td>Pending</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editTasks_50" value="50" id="editModal">Edit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div id="editTasks_50" class="modal fade show" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Update">
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Arslan On what browser are you opening that? Because I checked on chrome and firefox and on both it works properly.

Comment: I checked again now its working. Thank u for supporting

Answer (score 1):

What I would say is close all the modals that are opened and then open only the modal you want. Something like:

```
$("#editModal").click(function() {
  var id = $("#editModal").val();

  $('.modal').modal('hide');
  $('#' + id).modal('show');
});
```

> Since all modal have a common class 'modal' it will close all the
>   modal and show the modal you want.

Hope this helps!!
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more dynamic.

```
let modals = [
    {
        'callToAction': 'toggleVisitorProfileModal',
        'modalToToggle': 'visitorProfileModal'
    }, {
        'callToAction': 'toggleBuyTokensModal',
        'modalToToggle': 'tokensModal'
    },
];

$.each(modals, function (key, value) {
    $('.' + value.callToAction).on('click', function () {
            if ($('#' + value.modalToToggle).hasClass('in') === false) {
                $('.modal').modal('hide');
                $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                $('#' + value.modalToToggle).modal('show');
            }
        }
    )
});
```

Whenever you click an element to activate a modal

- Check if the current modal is open. An open modal has the IN class
  associated. If this is false we know that the modal you try to open
  is currently NOT open.
- We then close all modals.
- When there are multiple modals on the same page you might come across the black background not disappearing. To remove this we remove all elements containing the MODAL-BACKDROP class.
- And last we show the modal that is toggled.

Answer (score 0):

Closing all Modals in background

**$('.modal').modal('hide');**

Now, opening new Modal

**$('#myModal').modal('show');**

*I know this post is too old but I spend a lot of time in this type of issues and it's a simple solution by hiding modals in the webpage and then show new modal*

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mymodal').modal('hide');
```

it works correct,
If not closing modal then use below script

```
$('#mymodal').modal('hide');
$('div.modal-backdrop.fade.in').attr('class','none');
```